# Counting homomorphism between groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Until now I've done counting homomorphism $G \to G_2$ exercises in which $G$ is a cyclic set. I know that in this case the number of $Hom$ is totally determined by the generators image. So if I have a non-cyclic group how should I work for counting $Hom$?
Can you give me some examples?

Comment: There's no general method. You're looking for subgroups of index $2$. For example, the alternating group is the only such subgroup of the symmetric group. There's just one such subgroup in a cyclic group of even order, even if there are many generators.